# Corn cutting on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, maseches-shabbos, borer-separating

Is one allowed to cut corn off the cob with a knife or circle cutter on Shabbat? Would it be an issue of borer? Or would it be permitted? Does it change Sephardic Vs ashkenazi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to the [Sefer Shabbos Kehilchasa, Vol 2 p.321-22](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/26971/p/335/t/3977024591234/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c)

> הפוסקים נחלקו האם מותר להסיר הגרגירים מהקלח - ויש אסרו לעשות זאת, גם כאשר נעשה לאלתר בסמוך לאכילה. אלא שכל זה כשמוציא גרגירים ממקום חיבורים, אבל אם חותך בסכין באופן ששורשי הגרגירים נשארים במקומם בגוף קלח התירס, ורק חלקם העליון שאינו תקוע בקלח נחתך - מותר לעשות כן בסמוך לאכילה. ולנגוס בשיניו בקלח התירס, ולאכלו כדרכו, מבלי שמפריד לפני כן הגרגירים ממנו - מותרבכל אופן
>
> The poskim differed on whether it is permissible to remove the grains from the cob - and some forbade doing so, even when done immediately near eating. Except that all this is when removing kernels from a place of connections, but if you cut with a knife in such a way that the roots of the kernels remain in their place in the body of the corn cob, and only the upper part that is not stuck in the cob is cut - it is permissible to do so near eating. And bite the corn cob with his teeth, and eat it as he normally would, without first separating the kernels from it - it is permitted in any case.

Refer to the footnotes for further discussion.